Defining The Compound Interest Formula (for any standard period)
Here is the situation:
Terminology & Assumptions: I assume that nominal interest rate is not necessarily annual. I refer to its period, as NIR period. The effective interest rate, which take compounding into account is abbreviated as EIR. Given any exercise were the nominal interest rate, the NIR period is given, and one is asked to find the EIR for a specific period which in my case does not match the NIR period. (Notice if the general rule outlined below is to confusing jump to the example below firs; maybe that helps)
My Understanding/Definition of formula:
General compound interest formula: (1 + i/n )^(n x t) – 1,
i is nominal interest rate given, n is the number of compounding periods within that NIR period, and t =

The fraction of NIR period that is t, if EIR period < NIR period
The number of NIR periods that fit in t, if EIR period > NIR period
Otherwise, it is simply 1, if EIR period = NIR period.

First, I will check if the compounding period = the NIR period, as then n = 1 and the formula become simpler. If yes, then we have NIR with same period compounding otherwise we have NIR with different period compounding.

NIR with different period compounding: Uses (1 + i/n)^(n x t) – 1
NIR with same period compounding: Uses (1 + i)^t – 1 (simplified due to n = 1)

My interpretation of the formula: Notice that in the formula if you multiply it by 1 at the beginning than it makes more sense as you would calculate the nominal compound interest in case of principal of 1 and then at end subtract principal (1) again leaving only all interest (non-coincidentally in percentage decimal form).
EXAMPLE 1
Find weekly effective interest rate. We are given NIR per 2 year of 1 % and interest is compounded bi-monthly.
My Solution:
Here we first determine that there are 12 compounding periods in 2 years and t is 1/ 104 since a week is 1/104 of NIR period. This means (1 + 0.01/12)^(12 x (1/104)) – 1. The decimal that results is the effective interest rate. Multiplying by 100 gives the actual percentage. But this is not really accurate as we want since we are missing 1 day after 52 weeks in a 365 year. Therefore, it better to either first determine daily effective interest rate and then turn into weekly interest rate or to just directly determine the exact fraction a week is of 2 years or 730 days. This means (1 + 0.01/12)^(12 x (1/730)) – 1 = 0.00001369301929 followed by (1 + 0.00001369301929)^7 = ca. 0.0096 percent. But also possible is simply say that t is roughly 1/104,29 since a week is 1/104,29 of 2 years. So (1 + 0.01/12)^12 x (1/104,29) – 1.
Question 1: Is my understanding/definition (regarding the definition/understanding section above) correct?
Question 2: In the formula for compound interest I perceive (i/n) as the nominal interest rate per compound period. Is this the correct interpretation?
Why am I asking this: Well, I have seen questions about this topic, and none of them really talk about how the compound interest formula is not only usable on annual basis but you can also use it to for example turn semi-monthly effective interest rate into the annual nominal interest rate or vice versa. What I also wonder, is that I could not find a clarification regarding the fact that compound interest formula gives the relationship between nominal interest rate and effective interest rate whereas their periods (NIR and EIR periods) do not necessarily have to the same. This gives an entirely different perspective on the formula from the standard textbook view. I hope this post can clarify versatility of the compound formula.
If any questions, please ask.

tl;dr -- There is a virtual finance calculator and its user's guide you find here, which was written for an average target audience. Formulas -- which distinguish if payments are made at the beginning of a compounding period or at the end -- you find in Appendix D. HTH

Thanks. I read it, but it kind of helped with another question I had. But for the question I asked here not really. To summarize I want to know wether general compound interest formula: (1 + i/n )^(n x t) – 1 can be viewed in terms of i being the interest rate per any period (including but not limited to annual) and then base every other parameter (n and t) on the period of i. How exactly I tried explaining in Definition of formula section.

Sorry if my hint to the HP12C doesn't solve your problem. It's all I may offer as help.
